# Fortify Allowed header option

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, fortify, core-api

I am building a RESTful API. When the client uses an unsupported method such as GET on a resource that does not supports it, I am returning a 405 with the Allow header which lists the allowed methods:

Response

Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Allow: DELETE, PUT, POST

Connection: keep-alive

Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 00:19:26 GMT

Fortify display insecure HTTP method(s) on the web server.
How fortify determine insecure Http methods ?

Comment: Secure is HTTPS which uses TLS for encryption.  TLS is performed before the request is sent to establish an encryption mode.  If TLS fails than not request is sent by client.  See HTTPS Only : https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2021/06/01/available-for-preview-automatic-https-helps-keep-your-browsing-more-secure/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Thanks! Fortify shows insecure HTTP these verb  PUT & DELETE

How to make secure for PUT & DELETE verb as per fortify recommends?

Comment: Client needs to change HTTP to HTTPS.  It may not be that simple because TLS may fail for lots of different reasons.  If you are using the latest versions of apps the TLS bugs have been fixed provided you are using TLS 1.2 or 1.3.  The main reasons TLS fails today is due to proxies and if certificates are not compatible on client and server.